Custom Claims in a Multitenant Microsoft Entra App
I have a "multitenant and personal" Entra app that should allow users with all kinds of Microsoft accounts to log into it.
I need to add some custom claims to the ID token returned by this app (specifcially, the user.jobtitle and user.officelocation claims). I've done this by adding "Additional Claims" for the app in question in the Microsoft Entra Admin Center, as detailed here. The configuration looks like so:

Since this is a multitenant app, I have to configure custom signing keys as detailed here. I've done that with the Microsoft-provided Powershell script.
With these configurations in place, I can now get an OIDC ID token. However, there's a major limitation.
The ID token only includes the new custom claims for users in the same tenant that the app exists. i.e. if the app is in tenant aaaa-....-aaaa and I authenticate using a Microsoft account (that has values for the Job Title and Office Location properties) in tenant aaaa-...-aaaa, the values are included as claims in the ID token. But, if I authenticate using a Microsoft account (that also has these same properties populated) from tenant bbbb-...-bbbb, these claims are not included.
I cannot figure out why; it's a multi-tenant app and the custom claims are configured on the app itself, not on the Entra user directory or something else that would be specific to my tenant.
How can I get these custom claims for users from all tenants, instead of just my own?

For sample, I created a Multitenant application and added custom claims like below:

I generated tokens via Postman:
Grant type: Authorization code 

Callback URL: https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback
Auth URL:  https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
Token URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
Client ID : ClientID
Client Secret : ClientSecret
Scope: api://ClientID/.default openid


I signed in with the home tenant user that is the user exists in the tenant where the app resides, and I got the claims successfully:
ID Token:

Now when I tried to sign in with other tenant user, claims are not displayed:
ID Token:


Note that: Custom claims are tenant specific by default. If the claims are created in the TenantA then only the users residing in TenantA will get the claims in token.


Every tenant has its own set of claims and attribute mappings and hence claims configured in one tenant might not be available in another tenant.

To resolve the issue, you need to add the claims in the Enterprise application or Service Principal created in the other tenant like below:

Now the custom claims are displayed successfully for another tenant user too:

The claims are displayed in access token too.
Reference:
Custom SAML claim configured in multitenant Azure AD app is not copied to this app in another tenant - Stack Overflow by me

I saw this answer in another question after posting this. I need to find a way to do this without requiring an admin in Tenant B to make any configuration changes though. Is that possible?

No it is not possible to do so

What about getting a token that would allow calling a Graph endpoint (as the user) to obtain those properties? Maybe the /me endpoint?

Yes you can do that

Would you be able to provide details on that? When I get an access token and try to call that endpoint, I get an access denied error.

You need to grant user.read delegated api permission to the application to make it work

Yep, that does it, thanks! If you're also familiar with B2C, here's a follow-up question regarding how to achieve this in a B2C custom policy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78924141/azure-b2c-custom-policy-rest-call-with-bearer-token-from-oidc-step
